# Determinar si un lado (cara) de un objeto es visible en una matriz de proyección?

Tags: unity, unity3d, matriz

Se que es una pregunta un tanto complicada y dada mi falta de conocimiento en el tema me extenderé en la explicación, pido disculpas de antemano

La cuestión es la siguiente, deseo determinar que lados (caras) de un cubo son actualmente visibles desde una vista con perspectiva, pero no logro determinar esto con matemática simple, la idea que tuve en un comienzo fue calcular el vector direccional entre el objeto en cuestión y el punto de vista (Cámara)

la lógica que apliqué para obtener el vector direccional es esta

```
X = Xc - Xo
Y = Yc - Yo
Z = Zc - Zo
```

o lo que es igual a

```
dir = cam.position - obj.position
```

y para determinar que lados son visibles debía evaluar el valor de cada eje de este vector resultante, pero me encontré con dos problemas:

1. determinar que caras son visibles con este método funciona solo si la cámara no cambiar de dirección (si no gira)
2. si la cámara se mueve en dirección al objeto el vector no cambia pero si que cambia lo que ve la cámara entonces no funciona para nada

entonces mi siguiente plan fue calcular el vector direccional basado en la matriz de proyección de la cámara (hasta ahora sin éxito) y aquí es donde estoy estancado, no tengo código para mostrar pero si un par de imágenes que identifican el problema

[image: Caso uno]
[image: Caso dos]

Como se muestra en las imágenes,  la cara inferior deja de ser visible pero el vector direccional sigue siendo el mismo

como ultima opción pensé en utilizar algún tipo de raycasting desde cámara para determinar la geometría visible (nunca lo he hecho pero según lo pienso puede funcionar)

y en esencia eso seria todo, quisiera poder determinar eso para poder optimizar la generación de mallado procedural en Unity, pero teorías o algunas practicas matemáticas me vendrían bien si tienen alguna sugerencia

hasta ahora considero que la "mejor" opción es usar de algún modo las normales o el vector direccional pero no tengo idea de como trabajar con proyección de matrices ni nada parecido

Creo que es necesario mencionar que esto es para optimizar una generación de malla procedural en unity estilo voxelart (mundo de cubos) y creo que el nombre correcto de esto es frustrum culling y occlusion culling pero es muy diferente hacerlo con una malla convencional que en un motor de voxeles y no consigo algún documento o articulo que por lo menos me guie por un buen camino (he buscado hasta en inglés)

gracias por la ayuda y por tomarse el tiempo de responder!

Comment: *(he buscado hasta en inglés)* -> Lo mejor de unity es la pedazo comunidad que tiene. Hay miles de personas trabajando con unity y tienen un foro genial donde todos los que están allí son usuarios diarios de unity. Aquí en SO seguro que alguno hay que pueda ayudarte... pero la cantidad de gente aquí que trabaja con unity es mínima (no tienes más que mirar lo poco que aparece la etiqueta). Seguro que si preguntas en su foro te podrán responder mucho más rápido. SO es una herramienta genial para encontrar soluciones... pero no la única!

Comment: Gracias por comentar, muy ético y acertado, haré eso, gracias por la sugerencia!